# Google Search Box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code for a Google Search Box. I want to reduce the size. I am putting it on a site using html and css.

```
    <script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '004761606621672356167:q2rk-jxubla';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Comment: So show us the css code, Luke

Comment: Can you change the size using JavaScript?

Comment: Size of what? Font, input width?

Comment: I want to make the box smaller so I can fit it in the top right corner

Comment: https://www.google.com/cse/docs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since search box is rendered directly on your page you can apply whatever styles you want to make it look as you wish. Just explore HTML structure of the rendered box and write necessary CSS tweaks.

For example:

```js
(function () {
    var cx = '004761606621672356167:q2rk-jxubla';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
```

```css
.search-box .gsc-control-cse {
    width: 200px;
}
.search-box input.gsc-search-button {
    background-color: #5FC34F;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-box">
    <gcse:search></gcse:search>
</div>
```

The only tricky thing is that you have to make sure your new CSS declarations have more precedence then imported google search box styles. That's why you have to make your selectors more specific. Like in my example I used one more parent selector `.search-box`.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, just reducing the code size:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        var d = document, t = 'script';
        var g = d.createElement(t);
        g.type = 'text/java'+t; g.async = true;
        g.src = (d.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=004761606621672356167:q2rk-jxubla';
        var s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
    })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Or, if you know it will only be http:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        var d = document, t = 'script';
        var g = d.createElement(t);
        g.type = 'text/java' + t; g.async = true; g.src = 'http://www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=004761606621672356167:q2rk-jxubla';
        var s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
    })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Not tested..

Comment: I think that OP wants to change box styles, making it smaller: `I want to make the box smaller so I can fit it in the top right corner`.

Comment: Oh right, didn't see that in the original question. And no CSS was provided so assumed it was code reduction.. my bad..

Answer (score 0):

inspecting with your browser you can find classes and id's then add new stylesto them and use `!important` to strict your new rules.

use like this-

```
.cse .gsc-control-wrapper-cse, .gsc-control-wrapper-cse {
    width: 200px !important;
    margin:0 auto !important;
}
```